# Detect Action caller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have Action which return partial view. This partial view is called from different web pages. I need to detect in ResultForm Action from which pages Action is called, what is the best way to do that?

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult ResultForm()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("ResultForm"......);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it as parameter:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "caller")]
public ActionResult ResultForm(string caller)
```

Notice how the cache must vary by this parameter. And when generating a link to this action simply make sure you pass the caller parameter with the request. Another possibility is to use the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property on the request but its value might not always be populated.